# perl subroutine output appending "1"

Tags: html, perl, templates

I'm playing with sub routines. It's all working as it should, but now I'm getting a random returned value of: **1** at the bottom of the page when I call the sub admin_view.

Home.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env -w perl
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';

use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use feature qw(switch);
use CGI::Simple;
use HTML::Template;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;
my $action = $cgi->url_param('cmd') || ''; #Set to: URL/?cmd=
my $mode = $ARGV[0]; #accept entry from terminal
print $cgi->header; #make html appear

if($action eq "") {
    #if URL/?cmd=
    $mode = "home";
}

if($action eq "admin_view") {
    #if URL/?cmd=admin_view
    $mode = admin_view;
}

given($mode){

when(admin_view) {
#html: Admin Mode & Display posts
    use rawr::template qw(admin_view);
    print &admin_view;
}

when(home) {
    print "Some home page";
}

##Default message
  default { print "mode not implemented" }
}
```

Template.pm

```
package rawr::template;
#template stuff

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
use HTML::Template;

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(admin_view);

sub admin_view {
# open the html template
##Yuck hardcoded but ok, works for now. some reason ../tmpl/admin_view.tmpl doesn't work
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => '/srv/mydomain/www/rawr/tmpl/admin_view.tmpl');
# fill some parameters
   $template->param(ALIAS => "Some User");
   $template->param(CONTENT => "Hardcoded Content");
   $template->param(DATE => "Date - change me");
   $template->param(TITLE => "Hardcoded - change me");

# send Content-Type and print the template output
   print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", $template->output;
}
1;
```

admin_view.tmpl

```
    <table border="1" id="container">
            <tr>
                    <td id="main_content">
                    <ul>
                    <li onclick="showmenu(this)">!<b>PROFILE</b>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
                            <li> Delete</li>
                            <li> Lock</li>
                            <br>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                            <TMPL_VAR NAME=ALIAS>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                            <TMPL_VAR NAME=DSP>
                    <br>
                </td>


<td id="main_content" class="opacity_box" >
<b><TMPL_VAR NAME=TITLE></b> <TMPL_VAR NAME=DATE>
            <br>
            <br>
                             <TMPL_VAR NAME=CONTENT>
            <br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The template outputs fine, but at the bottom of the page I get a random output of **1** after the last `</table>` tag

```
</table>1
```

Any solution to the issue? cheers

Comment: Tip: Always use `use strict;`!

Comment: Tip: Using `no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';` isn't wise. You should actually heed the warning and avoid smartmatching. Smartmatching *will* be changed in a backwards-incompatible way in an upcoming version of Perl.

Comment: Thanks, will amend. Any recommendations to achieve the save result? I tried using Switch & Switch::Plain but kept getting knocked down with its syntax. The cpan for switch states "Switch - A switch statement for Perl, do not use if you can use given/when" which is why I used when

Comment: `given ($mode) { when("admin_view")` => `if ($mode eq "admin_view")`

Comment: thanks, however if I add "use strict;" I now receive: Bareword "admin_view" not allowed while "strict subs" using your edit -- would this be bcause I have a subroutine called admin_view?

Comment: found it, `$mode = admin_view;` should be `$mode = qw(admin_view);` -- thxs :)

Comment: `qw` is used when you have multiple words (e.g. `qw( foo bar )` as a "shortcut" for `"foo", "bar"`). You want `$mode = qq(admin_view);` or the equivalent but simpler `$mode = "admin_view";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your 'admin_view' sub does the print.

Thus you don't need to *call* it like this:

```
print &admin_view;
```

Because by doing so, it's printing the sub's return code. Which is the result of the last command without an explicit return, so shows us that `print` was successful.

Try just

```
admin_view;
```

(lose the `&` it's bad style)

Comment: Heh that simple, thanks. Did the trick and makes sense too. Can I ask why & is a bad example as I'm seeing it in many (I guess old) tutorials?

Comment: Yes. Because it's not needed, and all it does is a) disable prototypes, and b) pass `@_` into the sub. Both of which are probably not what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Sobrique, `&foo` isn't merely bad style; it actually does something quite special for which there is no need here!